# erewrite that asks for hypothesis first?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I want a variant of `erewrite` which asks for the hypothesis first, and then proceeds to the rewritten goal, rather than the other way round. Here is a small example:

```
Variable P : Prop.
Variable SomeProp: Prop -> Prop.

Lemma rewriter: forall (R: Prop), SomeProp R -> P = R.
Admitted.

Lemma useRewriter: P.
Proof.
  intros.
  erewrite rewriter.
  (* Current goal state, ?R *)
  (* I want SomeProp ?R first, not ?R *)
Abort.
```

I think SSR has some tactic like this, but I'm not able to find the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is on the bug tracker as [Premises of rewrite appear in different order](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/5706).

- The order was fixed in the SSR rewrite, and appears in the order that I ask for.
- The default rewrite (when not using setoid equality?) shows premises in the "wrong" order.

Comment: Indeed, that `rewrite` puts the sub-goals in the wrong order is indeed a well known issue that was never tackled. Until it changes, you can always use `; cycle 1` to reorder your goals.